# Can not make mongoose find().then() to work

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

Faced an issue with Mongoose.

```
import express from 'express';
import Countries from '../models/countries.mjs';

const router = new express.Router();

router.get('/countries-data', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let countries =
        await Countries.find({})
            .select(
                '-_id specimenDate dailyLabConfirmedCases changeInDailyCases')
            .sort('specimenDate');

    if (!countries) return res.status(500).send();

    res.json(countries);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send();
  }
});
```

This code works as expected but I decided to remove the async/await and use find().then() instead:

```
import express from 'express';
import Countries from '../models/countries.mjs';

const router = new express.Router();

router.get('/countries-data', (_, res) => {
  Countries.find({})
      .select('-_id specimenDate dailyLabConfirmedCases changeInDailyCases')
      .sort('specimenDate')
      .then((countries) => {
        if (!countries) throw Error('no data');

        res.json(countries);
      })
      .catch(res.status(500).send());
});
```

This one rise an exception while trying to send the json data:

*UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client*

I really don't know what I'm doing wrong. And why the catch isn't getting the promise exception? Any suggestion?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with .then code but just to be double sure :  add return before  res.json(countries);

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem arises from the response you sent in the `catch` block since the `catch` takes in a callback function which returns an error if there is any.

Try this:

```
import express from 'express';
import Countries from '../models/countries.mjs';

const router = new express.Router();

router.get('/countries-data', (_, res) => {
   Countries.find({})
  .select('-_id specimenDate dailyLabConfirmedCases changeInDailyCases')
  .sort('specimenDate')
  .then((countries) => {
    if (!countries) throw Error('no data');

    res.json(countries);
  })
  // refactor your code like this
  .catch((err)=>{
   res.status(500).send(err)
  });
```

});